# Extra characters added to end of string in c

Tags: c, string, printf

So I am trying to print out a string in C and I am consistently getting extra characters at the end of the string when I print it out.
The Code:

```
char binaryNumber[16] = "1111000011110000";
printf("binary integer: %s\n", binaryNumber);
```

Output:

> binary integer: 1111000011110000▒▒▒▒

can you please help me figure out why this is happening. I think this is the root of some other problems in my code. I had this problem before when I was creating the string in a more complex way, and got extra characters in that case too, but they were different. So I made a string the most basic way possible (method shown here) and am still getting the problem

Comment: Remember that strings in C have one extra character, that is the terminator character `'\0'`. Not having that terminator will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
char binaryNumber[17] = "1111000011110000";
```

This is because strings in C are null terminated. So you will be reading garbage if you don't give an extra character space for the implicit `\0` which will be added

Comment: Your string literal has 18 elements: the last two are equal (two `\0`s)

Comment: A string literal already has a null terminator (see link). So you have to either remove your `\0` and keep the `[17]`, or add one byte to store two null terminators. http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.4.5.html

Comment: does \0 count as 1 character or two in this case?

Comment: @bs7280  1 character as it is an escape sequence.

Answer (score 6):

Let the compiler determine the amount of elements needed

```
char binaryNumber[] = "1111000011110000";
// same as
// char binaryNumber[17] = "1111000011110000";
```

Comment: thanks! this worked, I always knew that I needed a null charachtar but was always unsure if I needed the size to be 16 or 17, I know now and I understand c better knowing that I can do what you said (which is good because I have a test on this in two days). This fix also fixed my other problems not mentioned here, so thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have 16 characters in your array. and there is no place to hold a `\0` character.

`%s` prints a string until it encounters a `\0`

So what you are seeing is some garbage characters being printed out.Please make your string is `\0` terminated